# Teradata : OGRGeometryFactoryX::createFromWkt failed

Tags: teradata

As part of **Geospatial** analysis, we have created an `ST_GEOMETRY` field in `Teradata` and storing **GeoSequence** data. We are able to insert GeoSequence data type and able to execute **GeoSequence** methods. But, for certain cases we are unable to insert **GeoSequence** data.

Below is the problematic record where it is throwing below exception.

```
INSERT FAILED. [7548] 13 OGRGeometryFactoryX::createFromWkt failed.

Insert Query:
---------------------
INSERT INTO PLAP_TEMP.SHAPES_WORK
VALUES (7234, 'GeoSequence((
103.849156 1.288848,
103.848589 1.287925,
103.847986 1.286837,
103.8475 1.286561,
103.845948 1.28738,
103.842801 1.289602,
103.842306 1.289904,
103.841407 1.288665,
103.839099 1.288882,
103.8377 1.288771,
103.835302 1.289199,
103.8319 1.290346,
103.827 1.29049,
103.825797 1.28810
),
(
2017-03-01 23:51:59,
2017-03-01 23:52:10,
2017-03-01 23:52:24,
2017-03-01 23:52:48,
2017-03-01 23:53:25,
2017-03-01 23:53:31,
2017-03-01 23:53:46,
2017-03-01 23:54:19,
2017-03-01 23:54:32,
2017-03-01 23:54:51,
2017-03-01 23:55:23,
2017-03-01 23:56:01,
2017-03-01 23:56:40,
2017-03-01 23:56:39
),
(
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0
),
(0))'
);
```

The Lat-Lng values corresponds to Singapore.

Could anyone kindly help to review this query and identify what could be the issue.

Thanks and Regards,
~Paul

Comment: You want all that stuff after `7234` in a single column?  That seems odd, but if that's the case, what error are you getting back, beyond `insert failed`?

Comment: Hi, It's the GeoSeqence value after 7234.  There is no specific error beyond the one which I mentioned above!!!